# How to push system metric from one machine to another in linux using collectd?

Tags: linux, bash, collectd

I have two centos Machine, Machine A and Machine B. In **machine A i have installed collectd and influxdb**. So, the system metric from machine A is pushed  into influxdb using collectd. **I have installed collectd in machine B**. Now, **I need to push the system metric from machine B to the influxdb which is in machine A**.

Collectd uses the port 25826. When I run the below mentioned command in Machine A my output is:

**Machine A:**

```
command: netstat -tuplen | grep ':25826'
 output : udp6       0      0 :::25826  :::* 981  325073833  23132/influxd
```

**In Machine B:**

```
sudo netstat -tuplen | grep ':25826'
```

No output came

When i use below mentioned command in **Machine B:**

```
command:telnet "xxx.xx.xx.xx" "25826"
output:Trying xxx.xx.xx.xx...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xx.xx.xx: No route to host
```

How to create the host in machine B...So that i can push the metric from Machine B to Machine A...From both machine PING command is working

Comment: Start influxd on Machine B.

Comment: @Cyrus how to do that? Can you please help me...My idea is like i need to have only one server in on machine and i need to push all system metric from machineB to machineA

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). This page is intended for programming questions.

Comment: @Cyrus...Okay can you help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

In Machine A you are running Influx. Influx is listening on port `:25826.` This is what you see when you run `netstat -tuplen | grep ':25826' output : udp6       0      0 :::25826  :::* 981  325073833  23132/influxd`
If you want to send metrics from Machine B to influx on Machine A please edit the network plugin option for collectd on Machine B

It should like something like this

> Blockquote

```
LoadPlugin  network
<Plugin network>
Server "<Machine A IP>" "25826"
</Plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying... I added the same already...It's not working...Pls help me